# File location error when loading images

Tags: delphi

I'm using this to load a image at random from file but as soon as it gets to the last image it shows 'Cannot open file "C:\Users\Misty\Downloads\PAT\Ham.jpg" The system cannot find the file specified'

My images are names 1,2,3 etc so where does the system get ham.jpg?

```
procedure TfrmGame.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    arrPics[1] := 'Hen' ;
    arrPics[2] := 'Van' ;
    arrPics[3] := 'Pen' ;
    arrPics[4] := 'Cat' ;
    arrPics[5] := 'Fan' ;
    arrPics[6] := 'Hut' ;
    arrPics[7] := 'Cap' ;
    arrPics[8] := 'Dog' ;
    arrPics[9] := 'Hat' ;
    arrPics[10] := 'Ham' ;

    arrPath[1] := '1';
    arrPath[2] := '2';
    arrPath[3] := '3';
    arrPath[4] := '4';
    arrPath[5] := '5';
    arrPath[6] := '6';
    arrPath[7] := '7';
    arrPath[8] := '8';
    arrPath[9] := '9';
    arrPath[10] := '10';

   Randomize;
    Counter:=Random(10);
     sWord:=arrPics[Counter];
     imgTest.Picture.LoadFromFile(arrPath[Counter]+'.jpg');
     imgTest.Stretch := True ;
end;

procedure TfrmGame.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Mark,RoundCounter:integer;
begin
Mark:=0;
RoundCounter:=0;
for RoundCounter:= 1 to 10 do
begin
if sWord=edtWord.Text then
begin
Inc(Mark)
end;
Randomize;
Counter:=Random(10);
  sWord:=arrPics[Counter];
    imgTest.Picture.LoadFromFile(arrPath[Counter]+'.jpg');
  imgTest.Stretch := True ;
edtWord.Clear;
```

Comment: As a small side note: it's meaningless to set `RoundCounter := 0;` right before you have `for RoundCounter := 1 ...`.

Comment: Read the [documentation for the `random` function](http://delphi.about.com/library/rtl/blrtlRandom.htm). `Random(10)` will yield a random number between `0` and `9`, not between `1` and `10` which is the valid range of your index. Use instead, `Random(10) + 1`.

Comment: @lurker Even better suggestion would be to use `RandomRange` from `Math` unit to generate random number from specific range.

Comment: @SilverWarior indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `n` is a positive integer, then `random(n)` returns a random number *greater than or **equal** to `0`* and *strictly **less than** `n`*. Since your array indices are 1 to 10, you need a random number in that range, but `random(10)` produces a number from 0 to 9. So your `Counter` may sometimes be `0`, which means you're attempting to access `arrPath[0]`, which is outside of the range of that array. In this case, it is accessing the item before it in memory, which is `arrPics[10]`. Do you have real-time range checking turned off in your settings? If you have it on, then Delphi will generate an exception for an array index out of range.

To get a random number from 1 to 10, use: `Counter := random(10) + 1`. Or, more simply, you could use `Counter := RandomRange(1, 10);`.